# Second time calling class program breaks, Java

Tags: java, swing

Alright, please bear with me here as i am really new.
To keep it simple and short i have class that has an jButton (on login frame) which has an action that is supposed to open frame from another class like this:

```
if (user.contains("admin") && pass.contains("admin"))
            {
                Admin adminProz = new Admin();
                adminProz.setVisible(true);
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
```

And for time being it worked great, but then i went back to "login" page for second login try, and compiler breaks... Following is the text i got in console:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is displayable.
at java.awt.Frame.setUndecorated(Unknown Source)
at prozori.Admin.<init>(Admin.java:50)
at prozori.LoginWin.<init>(LoginWin.java:53)
at prikaz.Logout$1.actionPerformed(Logout.java:36)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I believe the message is teely you that you can't invoke `setUndecorated()` on a frame that you have used pack() or setVisible().

Comment: Just a little dogma regarding, *"and compiler breaks..."* -- no compiler was injured in this attempt

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @camickr, commenting out `setUndecorated()` did made it work out, but now "admin" frame is decorated and i don't want that, i don't get where i am making core error because it cracks only when i run it for the second time.

Comment: We don't have access to your code so we can't tell you the exact line to change. The problem is on line 50 in your "Admin" class. The order of your statements is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are trying to call shouldn't be called after the Frame has been made visible.

This is covered in the documentation for [java.awt.Frame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated(boolean))

Excerpt from the javadoc:

```
This method can only be called while the frame is not displayable.

Throws:
  IllegalComponentStateException - if the frame is displayable
```

So, simply move where you call `setUndecorated` to before your Frame is displayed.